# ADO, Stored Procedures and Closed Recordset

Tags: c++, sql, ado, recordset

In the project I am working in, we have a component that lets us interact with product database.

It has a function to run the query directly onto the database.

It is using the code below

```
IDispatch ThatComponent::ProcessQuery(BSTR query)
{

    pRecordset.CreateInstance(__uuidof(ADODB::Recordset));
    pRecordset->AddRef();

    pRecordset->Open(_bstr_t(QUERY), (IDispatch *)m_pConnection, ADODB::adOpenStatic, 
        ADODB::adLockOptimistic, ADODB::adCmdText);
    pRecordset->PutRefActiveConnection(NULL);

    return pRecordset;
}
```

Now, using this component I need to run a stored procedure and retrieve it's return value and one output parameter.
To do so I am creating the query thus and passing it to ProcessQuery() function above.

"DECLARE @RC int; declare @realrecordid int; exec @RC = IncrementRecordCount currentRecordId, @realrecordid OUTPUT; select @RC AS RC, @realrecordid AS ID;"

The stored procedure does not return any recordset.

The problem is, when the recordset is returned it is closed. And I cannot do *any* operations on it.

Looking at the query above I imagine there will be two recordsets. One for exec statement and one for select statement.

Is there a way I can get to second recordset from the first closed recordset?

Thanks in advance,
-Neel